# How to detect a tap gesture using touchesBegan and touchesEnded

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've created a custom control which derives directly from a class `UIView`. Now I want to perform an action if a user tap on a particular part of my view. So I've overrided methods `touchesBegan`, `touchesEnded` and `touchesCancelled`. The problem is, that the method `touchesEnded` is never invoked, if I just tap on the display. The method `touchesCancelled` is called insted of it. `touchesEnded` is invoked only if I perform some gestures (swipe, move, ...).

Do I need to configure my view anyhow to enable tap gestures?

My code:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"touchesBegan");
    self->touchDown = YES;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:^{
        self.value = 1.0;
    } completion:nil];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self->touchDown) {
        NSLog(@"touchesEnded");
        self->touchDown = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.value = 0.0;
        } completion:nil];
    }
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if (self->touchDown) {
        NSLog(@"touchesCancelled");
        self->touchDown = NO;
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.value = 0.5;
        } completion:nil];
    }
}
```

For a tap gesture I get:

> 2018-07-17 09:55:20.994645+0200 iOS Test[33049:2763212] touchesBegan
>
> 2018-07-17 09:55:21.092409+0200 iOS Test[33049:2763212] touchesCancelled

Comment: Have you tried to subclass the UIView class with your code and adding a gestureRecognizer?

Comment: Yeah, UITapGestureRecognirer works perfectly fine, but I would like to avoid using gesture recognizers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried to set `recognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;` on your view

> A Boolean value affecting whether touches are delivered to a view when a gesture is recognized.

Comment: No, I didn't. But I don't use gesture recognizers in my custom View. Methods `touchesBegan`, ... come directly from UIView.

Comment: Check if you have gesture recognition active on any of the view controllers involved and if so turn it off. Your problem looks alot like there is a recognizer canceling your touches somewhere

Comment: OK, I realized, that I have a global gesture detector in my UIController. So this really helps me to solve my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should go through this.

From Apple documentation,

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uigesturerecognizer?changes=_4&language=objc

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{ 
   // Sent to the gesture recognizer when one or more fingers touch down in the associated view.
}


- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    //Sent to the gesture recognizer when one or more fingers move in the associated view.
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
   //Sent to the gesture recognizer when one or more fingers lift from the associated view.
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
 {
   //Sent to the gesture recognizer when a system event (such as an incoming phone call) cancels a touch event.
 }
```

Comment: I've read documentation and for UIView::touchesEnded there is written "Tells the responder when one or more fingers are raised from a view or window.". But it's not how it behaves in my application.